# Is there implicit racism in the word guerrilla?

Tags: confusables, homophones, racism

The pronunciation of the word "guerrilla" is a close homophone to the word "gorilla".

Is there any implicit racism in the **origin or later usage** of the word "guerrilla", based perhaps on the inferior view of gorillas as black, rude, uncivilized creatures? Could it reflect perhaps an ideological construct to de-legitimize the goals and actions of "guerrilla" groups, just like denoting a group as "terrorist" immediately de-legitimizes its actions?

Comment: Of course not! Look here for the etymology of guerrilla [link](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=guerrilla)

Comment: I stopped making toast years ago when I noticed the racist connotations of "griller".

Comment: I do detect a difference in nuance between "terrorist" and "freedom fighter."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[Guerilla](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=guerrilla)*** has nothing to do with [gorilla](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=gorilla) and I don't think it carries  a "racist" nuance because the two terms are homophones. Guerilla just refers to a specific warfare which is generally  irregular and  not well organized.

> - ***"fighter in an irregular, independent armed force," 1809, from Spanish guerrilla "body of skirmishers, skirmishing warfare," literally "little war,"***  diminutive of guerra "war," from a Germanic source cognate with Old High German werra "strife, conflict, war," from Proto-Germanic *werra- (see war (n.)). Acquired by English during the Peninsular War (1808-1814), when bands of Spanish peasants and shepherds annoyed the occupying French.
> - Purists failed in their attempt to keep this word restricted to "irregular warfare" and prevent it taking on the sense properly belonging to guerrillero "guerrilla fighter." Figurative use by 1861. As an adjective from 1811.

(etymonline)

Comment: Thanks. I'm not only itnerest in the origin of the word but also in its later usage. See updated question

Comment: @luchonacho - My answer is in the introductory line, etymology is just additional information. Plus, why should "gorilla" be a derogatory" term?

Comment: @Josh61 in American context, calling a person a `gorilla` or a person's actions `gorilla like` most assuredly is considered racist.  Using the word `gorilla` when talking about Harambe of the Ohio zoo, is not.

Comment: @USER_8675309 I'm an American and I've never seen or heard *gorilla* used in a racist way, nor would I expect anyone to interpret the word as a racist slur (though it still could be used as a generic insult, as in characterizing the person as a big dumb lug or mindless animal [though in reality gorillas are far from mindless]). In fact, during the mid-20th century, at least, *gorilla* was used as a dysphemism (a term of abuse used as a term of endearment), as in. *Get over here, ya big gorilla*.